# Equivalent optimization problems?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, numerical-optimization

I am wondering if the set of optimizers of the problem

$$ \min_{x \in X} \ f(x) \quad \text{subject to: } g(x) \leq 0, \ h(x) = 1  $$

is the same of the one of

$$ \min_{x \in X} \ f(x) + h(x) \quad \text{subject to: } g(x) \leq 0, \ h(x) = 1,  $$

given that the quantity $h(x)$ is anyways constant.

Minimizing $f$ should be the same of minimizing $f+1 = f+h$. Not sure am I right.

Comment: This is correct.